# How to prevent tramp from blocking when entering password?

Tags: tramp, async, sudo

For [my speech recognition mode](https://github.com/jgarvin/mandimus) I have emacs listen asynchronously using `make-network-process` for messages sent by my python client. If I say anything that should translate to emacs taking an action the python client send an elisp snippet to execute. To prevent bad code snippets from causing emacs to go unresponsive I wrap the code in a `with-timeout` as a failsafe.

The problem is if I use TRAMP to try to open say C-x C-f `/sudo::/tmp/foo`, emacs completely blocks on waiting for me to enter my password. Any packets sent by the client are ignored -- emacs isn't pulling any data off the socket. This means that if I'm only using my voice with-timeout always fires, and even if I'm typing that day I need to type really quickly. This is weird because 99% of the time minibuffer prompts don't do this -- usually the rest of emacs keeps running.

Is there a way to have tramp mode not completely block? Maybe a custom command prompting for the password that sticks it in tramp's password cache so that tramp's command to ask doesn't fire?

Comment: How about using an external utility such as `sshpass` or configuring a password file such as `auth-sources`?  `(defun my-remote-login () (interactive) (let ((auth-sources '("/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.authinfo"))) (find-file "/ssh:lawlist@12.34.56.789:/home/lawlist/")))`  The `auth-sources` file looks like this:  `machine 12.34.56.789 login lawlist password 12AB34cd port ssh`  Here is a helpful link that another forum participant wrote up:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22974359/2112489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with projectile mode in emacs 24+. [See here](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/issues/594). Quick fix is to eval the following:

```
(setq projectile-mode-line " Projectile")
```